# How to execute a stored procedure multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which i execute like this:

```
exec sp_storedProc '123','ME', '333',NULL
```

I have 400 different values I need to specify. How do I execute my stored procedure with different values at once?

Comment: Are they 400 different variations of 4 parameters? or are they 400 parameters?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may try to do it using CURSORS

```
DECLARE @param INT

DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT parameter FROM table_name WHERE ...

OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    EXEC sp_storeProc  @param
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @param
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to not to use cursors or while loop?

Comment: Thank you for this. Created a temp table and used above as an SP which inserted all results into that table. Worked like a treat!