# SQL Server 2014 execute stored procedure multiple times and Insert into table including parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, insert-into

I have a stored procedure that gets two parameters, `Date` and `EquipName`
and the result set is not stored in a table.

What I want to do is to run the stored procedure multiple times for different `EquipName` and for each result set, `INSERT` into only one table (`MyTable`).

The result of the stored procedure has 30 rows.

To do that I am using below code.

Thanks to [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782075/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-multiple-times)

```
DECLARE @EquipName INT

DECLARE curs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT EquipName 
    FROM EquipTable 
    WHERE ...

OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @EquipName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable
        EXEC sp_storeProc  '2018-01-01', @EquipName

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @EquipName
END

CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```

My question is:

Let's say, the stored procedure result has 5 columns but `MyTable` has **one extra column** `NameOfEquip`, and for every result set from the stored procedure, insert the `@EquipName` into all 30 rows of that result set.

How can I do that? `MyTable` is already created with right schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Each insert into the table, try updating the `NameOfEquip` for all values which are NULL. Maybe something Like this

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable
        EXEC sp_storeProc  '2018-01-01', @EquipName

UPDATE MyTable SET NameOfEquip = ISNULL(@EquipName,'') WHERE NameOfEquip IS NULL


    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @EquipName
END
```

Comment: Thanks jayasura  This works perfect, I also noticed for update line, this is also worked.  **UPDATE MyTable SET NameOfEquip = @EquipName WHERE NameOfEquip IS NULL**   it gave same result

Comment: I added the ISNULL because in case the value for @EquipName comes as NULL, then it might get updated with the Next NOT NULL Value. To be more Safer

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the results of the stored proc into a temp table, and then read from the temp table with the extra column and insert into 'MyTable'. 
Something like this:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (ColA INT, ColB INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
EXEC sp_storeProc  '2018-01-01', @EquipName

INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT *, @EquipName FROM @TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using `OPENROWSET`. You can find more details on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)

Following is the example for the same.

For example you have a SP like following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST
(
 @INPUT1 VARCHAR(10),
 @INPUT2 VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @INPUT1 AS COL1, @INPUT2 AS COL2
END
```

If you directly execute the SP

```
EXECUTE TEST 'A','B'
```

You will get output like following.

```
    COL1    COL2
   ------  ------
    A        B
```

To append a extra parameter to the result you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(COL1 VARCHAR(10), COL2 VARCHAR(10), COL3 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TBL(COL1,COL2,COL3)
SELECT A.*,GETDATE() 
from openrowset('SQLNCLI','Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;',
   'EXECUTE TEST ''A'',''B''') AS A

 SELECT * FROM @TBL
```

Output :

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
A        B      2018-02-21 09:09:03.257
```